# I can't use "pip install" directly

Tags: python, pip

I'm in the linux environment, and I can't use

```
pip install
```

to install everything. When I input something like

```
pip install numpy
```

It will give the error as below

```
Usage:   
  /opt/conda/bin/python -m pip install [options] <requirement specifier> [package-index-options] ...
  /opt/conda/bin/python -m pip install [options] -r <requirements file> [package-index-options] ...
  /opt/conda/bin/python -m pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  /opt/conda/bin/python -m pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  /opt/conda/bin/python -m pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

trueno-cache-dir = true is not a valid value for user option, please specify a boolean value like yes/no, true/false or 1/0 instead.
```

But if I use this command

```
sudo python -m pip install
```

It will work. What's wrong with this?

Comment: `pip` might be an alias. Could you see what the results are of the following commands: `which pip` and `type pip`.

Comment: Of course, I assume your package isn't installable by Conda itself; that should be the first course of action in a Conda environment.

Comment: @0 0 Both of these give me the path `/opt/conda/bin/pip` in bash.

Comment: Can you see what is inside the pip executable? First try with `file /opt/conda/bin/pip`, then with `wc -l /opt/conda/bin/pip` (if the `file` command indicates it is not a binary file), and if there are not hundreds of lines, then just `cat /opt/conda/bin/pip`. The pip executable is usually is a wrapper of 5-10 lines of Python that calls the package itself.

Comment: @0 0 With `file /opt/conda/bin/pip`, it gives me `/opt/conda/bin/pip:Python script, ASCII text executable`. For `cat /opt/conda/bin/pip`, it seems regular (as you said this is a wrapper of 5-10 lines)

Comment: Very odd (also given that the error message shows `/opt/conda/bin/python -m pip`, not `pip` or `/opt/conda/bin/pip`). What is the first line of the `pip` wrapper script (the hash/shebang)? That should point to the relevant Python executable.

Comment: By the way, why do your first examples (that fail) use the user account, but last, succeeding, example, use `sudo`?

Comment: @0 0 The first line in the wrapper is `#!/usr/bin/python`

Comment: That's definitely not `/opt/conda/bin/python`, which would make more sense. I'm not sure what exactly is going on, but this is definitely a problem.

Comment: @0 0 Because if I just use `python -m pip install`, it doesn't work (with the same error message), and I remember that I found someone with the command `sudo` do work (but I forget where I found this example), that's why I use `sudo`.

Comment: `sudo` will ignore some of your user settings. But it is also easier to mess up your system when using `sudo` (which, in a way, may already have happened). Using `sudo` will install things system-wide, with the system-installed Python executable (`/usr/bin/python`), not the Python executable that came with Conda. You may end up with problems further down the line, but it's hard to debug this without getting hands on. You could have a look at the output of `env`, to see what environment settings may be interfering with your settings.

Comment: @0 0 Thanks you for your comment. Actually, I have tried many things to fix this problem, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go check your ~/.pip/pip.conf

I think there might be something like this

```
user = trueno-cache-dir = true
```

All you have to do is to add a breakline

```
user = true
no-cache-dir = true
```